# Is there a specific way of identifying indentation errors?

Tags: python

```
if grade >=  85:
  
   print(m)
 
 elif grade = 72 - 84:
  
   print(n)
 
 elif grade = 60 - 71:
 
   print(o)
  
 elif grade = 50 - 59:
 
   print(p)

else:
 
print(x)
```

When I hit run, it shows that there is an indentation error in the first elif:

```
elif grade = 72 - 84:
```

The error says I made a mistake with the placement of the colon (`:`).  Problem is I can't figure out what the mistake is.

The error goes like this

> IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

Comment: There is no indentation at all in the code you provide. If there is some in your original code, please let it appear here. If not, I strongly recommend that you take a basic tutorial about Python, or review your learning material, where these rules will be explained.

Answer (score 1):

After your `if/else` statement, in the next line you need to indent your code by spaces or tabs.(You need to follow only one throughout the script). In this case, it should be in this way:

```
if grade >= 85:

    print(m)

elif grade == 72 - 84:

    print(n)

elif grade == 60 - 71:

    print(o)

elif grade == 50 - 59:

    print(p)

else:

    print(x)
```

Comment: @BuddyBobIII Well, his question is about indentation errors and the reply deals with the issue. Please note that @SAI SANTOSH CHIRAG also included `==`, thus making the statement valid.

Comment: Yes he just edited it @J.M.Arnold

Comment: You get an invalid syntax error, if you put `" = "` for an `elif` statement.He cleared stated that it is an indentation error

Comment: @BuddyBobIII There hasn't been any edits to the post yet.

Comment: Yeah well he changed it. Saw it with my own eyes

Answer (score 1):

```
Indutation means after writing if,elif,else,while..etc we used ":" this 
symbol end. next line code we have to give the 4 space.
grade=50
```

watch this vide--- https://youtu.be/Cd-k6QQMa18
if grade >= 85:

```
    print("m")

elif grade == 72 - 84:

    print("n")

elif grade == 60 - 71:

    print("o")

elif grade == 50 - 59:

    print("p")

else:

    print("x")
```

Answer (score 0):

"=" is an assignment operator.
"==" is a comparison operator, your condition should be like this:

```
elif grade == 72 - 84:

     print(n)
```

Also for indentation, please check if all "if" and "elif" are aligned on same column

Comment: ah yes! thanks for pointing it out